# Payment calculation for video content creators using Google Analytics

Tags: mongodb, google-analytics, mongodb-query, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I'm interning at an ed-tech startup where we have to pay the content creators on the basis of video watch time using Google Analytics. The current approach suggested is this:

Report of google analytics.

[image: Google Analytics Report]

It shows video watched time of a particular video by a particular user. So, if there are 5 users and each watches 3 videos, there will be 15 entries. There could be thousands or even hundreds of thousands entries once the application scales.

The company wants to calculate the watch time of a video by all users on a particular day and pay accordingly on a per-day basis.

To avoid malpractices, they've suggested to fetch this whole report using Cron job every day and store this whole report in our MongoDB database. After that, to calculate the payment, we will run a query in the database which will check:

- if the user has watched a video more than it's total duration. (This will be checked for all the user entries that are present in that day's report for a particular video. And this will be performed for all the videos)
- If yes, it'll only consider the total duration. And if no, it'll take the original value which is less than the total duration of that particular video.

**At last, we'll take a sum of all the values and pay the user according to that sum.**

I find this approach very naive and not scalable.

What is your view/opinion?

Comment: It is not clear why is naive and respect to what, can you describe this aspect better?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Suppose the application has scaled and there are lakhs of entries everyday. So, we have to fetch those lakhs of entries every day and put it into the datebase. Run the query for each videoID separately every day to count their respective sum. Now, I'm not quite sure but this might increase the operation cost of the database maybe? Or is this approach optimal?

Comment: I don't understand why the video display should be longer than its duration. i.e. if someone watches the video 2 or 3 times in a day do you want to pay only 1 per day?

Comment: Yes, suppose a user watches a 10 mins video again and again and the watch time becomes 40 minutes for today, now we'll only take 10 minutes of that user. We have to do this for each and every user who has watched that video on that day. And also, for each and every video by running queries through the MongoDB database. So, do you think it is optimal or naive?

Answer (score 1):

What you propose can certainly be an approach, obviously for large numbers you will need a system that allows you to manage large amounts of data.

You could also use unique events (daily) for the video completion event (in case a user has seen the same video multiple times in multiple sessions in one day), that way knowing the length of the video you can divide it by the number of unique events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will surely try to pitch this one in.